# Trying to edit wp-config file on Google cloud platform but get this message

Tags: wordpress

Trying to edit wp-config file on Google cloud platform but get this message.

```
PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/var/www/html/wp-config.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/config
-command/src/Config_Command.php on line 192
```

Comment: I tried to change permissions but no luck

Comment: Have you tried to use `sudo` in front of your commands? Please provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

Your not logged in as a user that has the necessary permissions to edit the file.

Change the permissions on the file to allow your current user access or log in as a user that has the necessary permissions.

We are talking about Linux permissions here, google cloud platform is irreverent to your question.